# Method definition passed as argument

Tags: java, android, methods, arguments

I saw this code when looking at an Android example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText editNumber;
    Button btnCall = (Button) this.findViewById( R.id.btnCall);

    editNumber = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editNumber);
    btnCall.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    call();
                }
            });
    // ...
}
```

Here:

```
new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        call();
    }
}
```

is passed to `setOnClickListener()` as a parameter. What I don't understand is what code inside `{...}` does here? if `new OnClickListener()` calls the constructor, and the constructor returns an object, yes, object can be passed to method as a parameter, but what is:

```
{
    public void onClick(View v) {
        call();
    }
}
```

doing here? It looks like a method definition?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Perception said, it is an anonymous inner class. `btnCall.setOnClickListenter()` is expecting an argument that has the type `OnClickListener`. You could instantiate a concrete reference to an `OnClickListener` and pass that as an argument but if you are never going to refer to it again, sometimes it is easier to simply make an anonymous inner class.